# Jenkinsfile how to tag image with multiple tags

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

Trying to tag an image with multiple tags; first with jenkins build number, second with "develop".

Building image with declarative language

```
agent {
    dockerfile {
        filename 'Dockerfile'
        dir 'build/images'
        }
    }
```

Using `docker image ls`; I can see a new image has been created, how do I tag this image with a Jenkins build number? Also, any suggestions on how to push to a self-hosted registry would be appreciated.

I tried to add the `args` option (from the source below), the build fails with the error message below

```
args "-t artifactory.lab.watchtower:5050/lab/rocky:latest"
```

Results in

```
process apparently never started in /build/jenkins/jekins/jobs/rocky/workspace@tmp
```

I'm following the jenkins doco found [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent-parameters)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`agent` directive will tell Jenkins to run your pipeline within a specified agent. In your case, your pipeline will execute in a Docker container.

Inorder to build a new container you can use the Docker build option. Read more [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#building-containers).

Example:

```
node {
    def dockerfile = 'Dockerfile.test'
    def customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}",
                                   "-f ${dockerfile} ./dockerfiles")
    customImage.push()
}
```

**Update:** Using Docker step in a declarative pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('BuildDocker') {
            steps {
                // Get some code from a GitHub repository
                git branch: 'main', url: 'https://github.com/xxxxx/sample.git'
                sh "ls"
                script {
                    def dockerfile = 'Dockerfile'
                    def customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}")
                    customImage.push()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is using a scripted pipeline, I'm looking for a solution with the declarative language.

Comment: This supports both.

Comment: I don't use the "node" declaration, I currently build the docker image with agent { dockerfile { } }. The part of the doco linked is "Advanced Usage with Scripted Pipeline" so i'm not really sure how this translates to the declarative language

Comment: @researchbruz I have updated the answer, please have a look.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you prefer using the scripted language or declarative? Do you know which is considered better practice?

Comment: The declarative syntax is newer and I personally prefer declarative syntax.